# Nested async function with array map, empy response

Tags: arrays, node.js, function, async-await

The problem is that the variable `arrV` is empty when sent to res. I've tried to insert `.then()` function after the first async or calling `return new Promise` after `(async () => {` but the result is the same. I will paste main and other functions:

```
router.get('/telegram/chats', (req,res,next) => {
    let arrV = [];
    (async () => {
        let q = await Telegram.getChats();
        Object.keys(q).map(async (k, v) => {
            let search = await MTel.getChatById(q[k].id,(r) => {
                if(!r){
                    MTel.insertChat([q[k].id,q[k].title,q[k].last_message,0], (p) => {
                        arrV.push(p);
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    })();

    res.send(arrV);
});
```

Telegram.getChats():

```
async function getChats(options) {
    let ret = [];
    let ok = await client.getChats();
    for(var k in ok["chat_ids"]){
        let ch = await client.getChat(ok["chat_ids"][k]);
        ret.push({id: ch.id, title: ch.title, last_message: ch["last_message"].id});
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Mtel.getChatById() and Mtel.insertChat():

```
const getChatById = (id,callback) => {
    let qq = db.select(table,{id_chat: id},"LIMIT 0,1", (r) => {
        return callback(r);
    })
}

const insertChat = (obj,callback) => {
    let qq = db.insert(table,["id_chat","title","last_message","active"],[obj], (r) => {
        return callback(r);
    })
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest trying to change all your callback-based functions to use promises. That way you can easily await them on the calling side, and avoid some of your nesting. An issue in the current code is that your functions `getChatById` and `insertChat` are not awaited in the main function, so when you get to `res.send` those previous calls, may not have "finished" and called their callbacks (thus nothing has been added to `arrV`).

Comment: I tried to change all functions into `Promiseˆ then i used `await Promise.all()` with the `Object.keys(q).map(` function with `then()`at the end and it worked. Thank you so much.